# How to add time to time (minutes + minutes) in Javascript ? (Not to Date)

Tags: javascript, time, addition

I don't finde anywhere how to add time to time, like adding 45 minutes to 45 minutes and having 1:30 (1 hour, 30 minutes).
I just find how to add time to actual Date.

Heres an example in PHP of what I'm looking for:

```
$seconds_toadd = 45;// VALUE TO GET FROM A TEXTBOX
$actual_value = '00:45'; //45 minutes, 0 hours is the actual value
$resultado = new DateTime($lectura_xml);
$resultado->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $seconds_toadd . 'S'));//This is how I add seconds in PHP

$stamp = $resultado->format('I:s');//Formatting result

echo $stamp;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use momentjs library for time/date based functionlity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)** is a great library for date/time handling in JavaScript and better than the standard API and any homemade solution in many aspects.

---

Very simple but similar use case from [their docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/add/):

```
var a = moment.duration(1, 'd');
var b = moment.duration(2, 'd');
a.add(b).days(); // 3
```